# Related to HTML and JS it is giving only location output , date range is not working

Tags: javascript, html

The below is related to Location mapping and daterangepicker ,I combined code of location mapping and daterangepicker but It is giving only location mapping output , date range is not working when i debuged it is showing daterangepicker is not function and i put all the files in the same folder. and when i run separately both are working.please help me for the same.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>street light location</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
 <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="daterangepicker.css" /
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="moment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="daterangepicker.js"></script>
 <!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" />
 
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 450px;
        width: 690px;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        margin-top: 0.6em;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  var infowindow;
  var markers = [];

      function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var loca = new google.maps.LatLng(20.5937, 78.9629);

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          center: loca,
          zoom: 8
        });

      }

      function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var marker = markers.pop();
            marker.setMap(null);
            delete(marker);
          }
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
          }
        }
      }

      function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });
        markers.push(marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(place.name);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      }

  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("area").value;
    var state=document.getElementById("state").value;
 var city=document.getElementById("city").value;
 display1.innerHTML= state+"  ,"+city+" , "+address;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
        var request = {
          location: results[0].geometry.location,
          radius: 50000,
          name: 'ski',
          keyword: 'mountain',
          type: ['park']
        };
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
      } else {
        alert("Below are the mandatory Fields: " + status);
      }
    });
    return false;
  }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
   
    </script>
 
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Countries
        var country_arr = new Array("Select Country","INDIA","Africa");

        $.each(country_arr, function (i, item) {
            $('#country').append($('<option>', {
                value: i,
                text : item,
            }, '</option>' ));
        });

        // States
        var s_a = new Array();
        s_a[0]="Select State";
        s_a[1]="Select State|ANDHRAPRADESH|KARNATAKA|TAMILNADU|DELHI ";
        

        // Cities
        var c_a = new Array();
        c_a['ANDHRAPRADESH']="|HYDERABAD";
        c_a['KARNATAKA']="Select City|BANGALORE|Mysuru";
        c_a['TAMILNADU']="|CHENNAI";
        c_a['DELHI']="|DELHI";
  
  var a_a=new Array();
  a_a['BANGALORE']="Select Area|Indranagar|Koramangala";
  a_a['Mysuru']="Select Area|Rajnagar|NrColony";
  
  var b_a=new Array();
  b_a['Indranagar']="Select SubArea|Main|Lastmain";
  b_a['Koramangala']="Select SubArea|Raocircle|SbiStop";
  b_a['Rajnagar']="Select SubArea|aaaaa|bbbbb";
  b_a['NrColony']="Select SubArea|cccc|dddd";

        $('#country').change(function(){
            var c = $(this).val();
            var state_arr = s_a[c].split("|");
            $('#state').empty();
            $('#city').empty();
   $('#area').empty();
   $('#barea').empty();
            if(c==0){
                $('#state').append($('<option>', {
                    value: '0',
                    text: 'Select State',
                }, '</option>'));
            }else {
                $.each(state_arr, function (i, item_state) {
                    $('#state').append($('<option>', {
                        value: item_state,
                        text: item_state,
                    }, '</option>'));
                });
            }
            $('#city').append($('<option>', {
                value: '0',
                text: 'Select City',
            }, '</option>'));
        });

        $('#state').change(function(){
            var s = $(this).val();
            if(s=='Select State'){
                $('#city').empty();
                $('#city').append($('<option>', {
                    value: '0',
                    text: 'Select City',
                }, '</option>'));
            }
            var city_arr = c_a[s].split("|");
            $('#city').empty();

            $.each(city_arr, function (j, item_city) {
                $('#city').append($('<option>', {
                    value: item_city,
                    text: item_city,
                }, '</option>'));
            });


        });
  $('#city').change(function(){
            var s = $(this).val();
            if(s=='Select City'){
                $('#area').empty();
                $('#area').append($('<option>', {
                    value: '0',
                    text: 'Select area',
                }, '</option>'));
            }
            var area_arr = a_a[s].split("|");
            $('#area').empty();

            $.each(area_arr, function (j, item_city) {
                $('#area').append($('<option>', {
                    value: item_city,
                    text: item_city,
                }, '</option>'));
            });
        });
  
  $('#area').change(function(){
            var s = $(this).val();
            if(s=='Select Area'){
                $('#barea').empty(); 
                $('#barea').append($('<option>', {
                    value: '0',
                    text: 'Select barea',
                }, '</option>'));
            }
            var barea_arr = b_a[s].split("|");
            $('#barea').empty();

            $.each(barea_arr, function (j, item_city) {
                $('#barea').append($('<option>', {
                    value: item_city,
                    text: item_city,
                }, '</option>'));
            });
        });
    });
</script>

      

      </head>
   <style>
        body{
        margin-top: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size:15PX;

        }

    </style>
      <body style="background:url({{'/static/images/blurry.jpg'}}); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
        <h1>  </h1>
  <h4>Your Date Range Picker</h4>
    <div id="reportrange" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
     <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
    </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
     
     var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
     var end = moment();

     function cb(start, end) {
      $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
     }

     $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
      startDate: start,
      endDate: end,
      ranges: {
         'Today': [moment(), moment()],
         'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
         'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
         'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
         'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
         'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
      }
     }, cb);

     cb(start, end);
     
    });
    </script>
        <h1> Configuration  <img src='/static/images/small.jpg' alt="Smiley face" width="48" height="48" align="middle"></h1>
        <form onsubmit="return codeAddress()">
            
  Select County:
  <select name="country" id="country"></select>
  Select State:
  <select name="state" id="state"></select>
  Select City:
  <select name="city" id="city"></select>
  Select Area:
  <select name="area" id="area"></select>
  Select SubArea:
  <select name="barea" id="barea"></select><br>
            <p>Address :<span id='display1'></span></p>
    <form onsubmit="return codeAddress()">
        <!--<input type="text" id="address" placeholder = "12345" autofocus></input>-->
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="codeAddress();" ></input>
    </form>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="text">

 <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCvwPKqoD58pslC15Tx-iNdCV2xdeOqNGg&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
_uacct = "UA-162157-1";
urchinTracker();
</script>

        </div>
        </form>
        <br>
      

      </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: run the above snippet and check the errors

Comment: `Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery` - `ReferenceError: urchinTracker is not defined` - `TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function` - `You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.` - `"uncaught exception: InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function"`

Comment: well @JaromandaX did that for you. Now fix those errors and check still your issue exist or not

Comment: I didn't do anything, I just listed the errors in the "console" :p

Comment: Please see [*How to create a **minimal**, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know what is urchinTracker() - I comment it.
2. There are errors in console when choosing some select values - like "test.html:195 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined" . I didn't fix them. Open browser console (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/), view errors and test.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByQHLazSsLs-Yk4ybDBsVFBtXzg